# SharePoint 2013 Crawl and Index HP TRIM 8.1?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

Is it possible to perform a crawl and search from SPS 2013 (On-premises) to documents stored in HP TRIM 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but BA Insight sells a connector that supports both full and incremental crawls. http://bainsight.com/trim-connector-for-sharepoint

Alternatively you could attempt to create your own connector via the BCS.

Comment: Create connector via BCS, hmmm, can you share more information on it.

Comment: Bing around. This is the best book on the planet for this topic (though not specifically for HP): http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Business-Connectivity-Services-SharePoint/dp/047061790X